# Image Crop Not Working in Fragment

Tags: android, camera, fragment

Below is My Code which is working Nic when i am using Activity but when i implemet this code in fragment then after select image from gallery or capture from camera then its not showing crop option. also my image not showing in imageView.

Below is my Camera Handler:

```
public class CameraHandler {
    public static int IMAGE_PIC_CODE = 1000, CROP_CAMERA_REQUEST = 1001,
            CROP_GALLARY_REQUEST = 1002;
    private Intent imageCaptureintent;
    private boolean isActivityAvailable;
    Context context;
    private List<ResolveInfo> cameraList;
    List<Intent> cameraIntents;
    Uri outputFileUri;
    Intent galleryIntent;
    Uri selectedImageUri;
    private String cameraImageFilePath, absoluteCameraImagePath;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    ImageView ivPicture;

    String ivPicture1 = String.valueOf(ivPicture);

    public CameraHandler(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        setFileUriForCameraImage();
    }

    public void setIvPicture(ImageView ivPicture) {
        this.ivPicture = ivPicture;
    }

    private void setFileUriForCameraImage() {
        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "MyDir" + File.separator);
        root.mkdirs();
        final String fname = "image.jpg";
        final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, fname);
        absoluteCameraImagePath = sdImageMainDirectory.getAbsolutePath();
        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
    }

    public String getCameraImagePath() {
        return cameraImageFilePath;
    }

    private void getActivities() {
        imageCaptureintent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        PackageManager packageManager = ((Activity) context)
                .getPackageManager();
        this.cameraList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
                imageCaptureintent, 0);
        if (cameraList.size() > 0) {
            isActivityAvailable = true;
        } else {
            isActivityAvailable = false;
        }
    }

    private void fillCameraActivities() {
        getActivities();
        if (!isActivityAvailable) {
            return;
        }
        cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : cameraList) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(imageCaptureintent);
            intent.setPackage(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
                    resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName,
                    resolveInfo.activityInfo.name));
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            cameraIntents.add(intent);
        }
    }

    private void fillGallaryIntent() {
        galleryIntent = new Intent();
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    }

    public void showView() {
        fillCameraActivities();
        fillGallaryIntent();
        // Chooser of filesystem options.
        final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent,
                "Select Source");

        // Add the camera options.
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[] {}));

        ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(chooserIntent,
                IMAGE_PIC_CODE);
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {

        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(src, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 192, 256);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(src, options);

    }

    private int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
                                      int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2
            // and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null,
                    null, null);
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == IMAGE_PIC_CODE) {
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                    Log.v("", "ics");
                } else {
                    Log.v("", " not ics");
                }
                boolean isCamera;
                if (data == null) {
                    isCamera = true;
                } else {
                    final String action = data.getAction();

                    if (action == null) {
                        isCamera = false;
                    } else {
                        isCamera = action
                                .equals(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    }
                    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH
                            && action != null) {
                        Log.v("", "action = null");
                        isCamera = true;
                    } else {
                        Log.v("", "action is not null");
                    }
                }
                if (isCamera) {
                    selectedImageUri = outputFileUri;
                    onResultCameraOK();
                } else {
                    selectedImageUri = data == null ? null : data.getData();
                    onResultGalleryOK();
                }
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == CROP_CAMERA_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                resultOnCropOkOfCamera(data);
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                resultOnCroppingCancel();
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == CROP_GALLARY_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                resultOnCropOkOfGallary(data);
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                resultOnCroppingCancel();
            }
        }

    }

    private void doCropping(int code) {
        Log.v("", this.cameraImageFilePath);
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(selectedImageUri, "image/*");
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        try {
            ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(cropIntent, code);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    private void onResultCameraOK() {
        this.cameraImageFilePath = absoluteCameraImagePath;
        this.bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(cameraImageFilePath);
        doCropping(CROP_CAMERA_REQUEST);
    }

    private void onResultGalleryOK() {
        this.cameraImageFilePath = selectedImageUri.toString();
        this.bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(getRealPathFromURI(context,
                selectedImageUri));
        doCropping(CROP_GALLARY_REQUEST);
    }

    private void resultOnCropOkOfCamera(Intent data) {
        this.bitmap = data.getExtras().getParcelable("data");
        Log.v("", "cameraImageFilePath on crop camera ok => "
                + cameraImageFilePath);
        setImageProfile();
    }

    private void resultOnCropOkOfGallary(Intent data) {
        Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();
        this.bitmap = extras2.getParcelable("data");
        setImageProfile();
    }

    private void resultOnCroppingCancel() {
        Log.v("", "do cropping cancel" + cameraImageFilePath);
        setImageProfile();
    }

    private void setImageProfile() {
        Log.v("", "cameraImagePath = > " + cameraImageFilePath);
        if (ivPicture != null) {
            if (bitmap != null) {
                ivPicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                String ivPicture =ConDetTenthFragment.getStringImage(bitmap);

                Log.d("byte code -", ivPicture);

                /*Intent i = new Intent(context, ImageUpload.class);

                String getrec = ivPicture;

                //Create the bundle
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                //Add your data to bundle
                bundle.putString("moin", getrec);

                //Add the bundle to the intent
                i.putExtras(bundle);

                //Fire that second activity
                context.startActivity(i);*/

            } else {
                Log.v("", "bitmap is null");
            }
        }
    }

    public String getVar1() {
        return ivPicture1;
    }

    /*public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }*/
}


Below is my Fragment Code:


public class ConDetTenthFragment extends Fragment {

    static String FileByte;
    String FileName;
    String resultlog;

    ImageView ivProfile;
    Context context = getActivity();
    Button btnUpload, send;
    CameraHandler cameraHandler;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    static String abc;

       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.con_det_tenth_fragment, container, false);
           /*TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFragFirst);
           tv.setText(getArguments().getString("msg"));*/

           ivProfile = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.iv_upload);
           btnUpload = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_upload_image);
           send = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnsend);
           cameraHandler = new CameraHandler(context);
           cameraHandler.setIvPicture(ivProfile);

           // Progress dialog
           pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
           pDialog.setCancelable(false);
           pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait");


           btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {

                   cameraHandler.showView();

               }
           });

           send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   new async().execute();
               }
           });


       return rootView;
   }


    public static ConDetTenthFragment newInstance(String text) {

        ConDetTenthFragment f = new ConDetTenthFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("msg", text);

        f.setArguments(b);

        return f;
    }


    public static String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

        abc = encodedImage;

        //encodedImage = FileByte.setText().toString();

        return encodedImage;
    }

    // Async task to perform login operation
    class async extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            //Get the bundle
            /*Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

            //Extract the data…
            String stuff = bundle.getString("moin");*/

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespace, method_name);
            request.addProperty(parameter, abc);//add the parameters
            request.addProperty(parameter2, "moin.jpeg");

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);//set soap version
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            try {
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url);
                // this is the actual part that will call the webservice
                androidHttpTransport.call(soap_action, envelope);
                //  SoapPrimitive prim = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();  // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
                SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                //  resultlog=prim.toString();

                hideDialog();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return resultlog;

        }
    }


    /*@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == btnUpload) {
            cameraHandler.showView();
        }
        if (view == send) {
            new async().execute();
        }
    }*/

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        cameraHandler.onResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.v("", "code = > " + requestCode);
    }
    // this is used to show diologue
    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    // this is used to hide diologue
    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.

Comment: Thanks CommonWare. But my code also working fine in activity. i am struggling to implement this code in fragment. Crop option not giving and also not showing captured image in imageview.

Comment: "But my code also working fine in activity" -- there are thousands of Android device models. How many have you tested your app on? 1? 2? Do not rely on undocumented, unsupported, and frequently non-existent activities.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer to call the image crop in a fragment use

```
AddImage1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = CropImage.activity()
                        .setAspectRatio(16,9)
                        .getIntent(getContext());

                startActivityForResult(intent, CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
```

on the onActivityResult you must add an extra line `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);`

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
                Log.e("resultUri ->", String.valueOf(resultUri));
                AddImage1.setImageURI(resultUri);
            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
                Log.e("error ->", String.valueOf(error));
            }
        }
    }
```

This worked perfectly for me

Comment: You should use `Log.d` instead of `Log.e`.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/wiki/Using-built-in-CropImageActivity

You could check the official documentation, it stated how to get the cropped Uri on a fragment. Below is my code snippet.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        CropImage.activity(imageUri)
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .setAspectRatio(4,4)
```

//this was what I missed
.start(getContext(), this);

```
    }
    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
            Log.d("resultUri ->", String.valueOf(resultUri));
            imageViewProfilePicture.setImageURI(resultUri);
            mImageUri = resultUri;
        } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
            Exception error = result.getError();
            Log.d("error", String.valueOf(error));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i spent 8 hrs to find the error, why my Crop Image is not working in fragment. its started working after adding "this" , .start(getActivity(),this)